# JSON in MySQL, returning null results

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, select

In the department table, I have two fields:

- documentid, which is INT
- jsondocument which is JSON

I executed the following query:

```
INSERT INTO department VALUES
(1,'{"department":{
"deptid":"d1",
"deptname":"Marketing",
"deptroom":"Room 7",
"deptphone":["465-8541","465-8542","465-8543"],
"employee":[{
"empid":"e1",
"empname":"Mary Jones",
"empphone":"465-8544",
"empemail":["mjones@gmail.com","mjones@company.com"]},
{
"empid":"e2",
"empname":"Tom Robinson",
"empphone":"465-8545",
"empemail":["trobinson@gmail.com","trobinson@company.com"]},
{
"empid":"e3",
"empname":"Olivia",
"empphone":"465-8546",
"empemail":["ojohnson@gmail.com","ojohnson@company.com"]}
]}} ' );
```

Now, I am trying to return the deptname and the deptphone using this code:

```
SELECT 
    documentid,
    jsondocument->'$.deptname' as deptname, 
    jsondocument->'$.deptphone' as deptphone
from department;
```

However, it's returning null values. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect, as tabular text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are missing first-level key `department` in your json path:

```
select
    documentid,
    jsondocument->'$.department.deptname' as deptname, 
    jsondocument->'$.department.deptphone' as deptphone
from department;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b831edecce6333e4891540c42ec26360)**:

```
documentid | deptname    | deptphone                           
---------: | :---------- | :-----------------------------------
         1 | "Marketing" | ["465-8541", "465-8542", "465-8543"]
```

Note that this gives you `deptphone` as a json array - because that's how it is stored in the json document. If you want to unnest the array into several rows, then additional processing is needed (in MySQL 8.0, you would typically use `json_table()`) - you might want to ask a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

The deptname and deptphone are inside department,
So instead of .deptname, you have to use .department.deptname, same with the .deptphone, it will be .department.deptphone